# iOS how to inspect items on the main OS Dispatch Queue

Tags: ios, react-native, detox

I am developing an app using React Native and running end to end tests with Detox (this is for context but not particularly relevant). The e2e tool automatically pauses execution when it detects actions taking place, such as in flight network requests, animations, items on the main thread etc.

My problem is that my tests are hanging due to an item on the OS Dispatch Queue that is never dequeued. This is all the information that the tool gives me. Is there a way, perhaps through an Xcode debugger, that I can inspect items on the dispatch queue? Perhaps that might give me a clue as to the nature of the items on the queue which might in turn help me find out how to prevent enqueuing them or removing them from the queue.

If this isn't the best place to ask perhaps you might point me to a more suitable place. Thanks

TLDR: How can I view items on the main OS Dispatch Queue?